# Splitting a 2D array into smaller equally sized 2D subarrays

Tags: java

Basically what I am asking is given a square 2D array and a valid patch size (the size of the 2D subarrays) how would I go about doing this.
Ultimately I don't need to store the subarrays in any way, I just need to find the median of each subarray and store them in a 1D array. The median and storing to new array are simple for me, I just can't figure out how to go about the original 2D array and splitting it properly.
I've attempted this several times and keep getting out of bounds errors.
I have a 4x4:

`[1,2,3,4]
 [2,3,4,1]
 [3,4,1,2]
 [4,1,2,3]`

I need to split it like so

`[1,2] [3,4]
[2,3] [4,1]`

`[3,4] [1,2]
[4,1] [2,3]`

And then take the median of each and store them into a new 1D array.

EDIT: Solved, thanks for the help!

Comment: May be a small mistake in the way you pick the indexes. Could you post some code? It might be easier to spot the error that way.

Comment: Okay I've added in my code, it does not include getting the median at this time.

Comment: What happens?  How does this differ from what you expect?  "Find the error in this code" isn't really considered an appropriate way to ask questions on SO.

Comment: I never asked anyone to find the error, I simply don't understand why I'm getting an error.

Comment: @Nick what are you returning via `pArray`?? is this the array of all the combinations? Also show the error message.

Comment: pArray should return the median of each subarray that is obtained from your code. I know how to sort and get the median already I just haven't implemented it.

Comment: @Nick How are you calling `patchArray` method and what error are you getting ? Code looks fine to me.

Comment: I've figured it out. And I cannot believe I let it slide. I have a method that normalizes the size of the array and I forgot to set the old array to that size. It works flawlessly now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: happy to help.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(Object[] src, int from, int to)` for this where:

`src` is the source `1D` array

`from` is the initial index of the range to be copied, inclusive.

`to` is the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive.

I don't prefer your code because it seems that it's time complexity is too high.

Try below code:

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = { { 1,2,3,4 },
                        { 2,3,4,1 },
                        { 3,4,1,2 },
                        { 4,1,2,3 } };

        int patch = 2;

        splitToSubArrays(arr, patch);

    }

    static void splitToSubArrays(int arr[][], int patch) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
            int to = patch;
            for (int from = 0; to <= arr.length;) {
                int a[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr[i], from, to);
                // instead of printing you can store in a separate array for later usage
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
                to += patch;
                from += patch;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

***EDIT:*** N.B.: For `n*n` array if `n%patch` is not `0` i.e. dimension is not divisible by  `patch` value then you would need to use proper `if` condition here `int a[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr[i], from, to);` to control the index bound. Hope you are aware of this.

***Output***

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[2, 3]
[4, 1]
[3, 4]
[1, 2]
[4, 1]
[2, 3]
```

Comment: I see what you've done here, and when I run it on my IDE it works, however when I try to implement into my code, I'm still getting an out of bounds error. For reference, the size of the array is 250x250 and the patch size is 25.

Comment: @Nick Yes .For `250x250` and the `patch` size is `25` it will work too. 
How are you trying to implement into your code?? I need to see that code.

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to SO. I edited my original post with your code. It's basically identical and still gives OoB.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this could do, altough i didn't test it, but It should give you a good idea of how to do this scan

```
public int[] patchArray(int[][] img, int patch)
{
    int size = img.length * (img[0].length / patch) ;
    int[] pArray = new int[size];
    int[] tmp = new int[patch];

    for (int row_i = 0; row_i < img.length; row_i++)
    {
        for (int patch_start = 0; patch_start < img[i].length; patch_start += patch)
        {
            int x = 0;
            for (int patch_i = patch_start; patch_i < (patch_start + patch); patch_i++)
            {
                tmp[patch_i - patch_start] = img[row_i][patch_i];
            }

            calculateMedian(tmp);
        }
    }

    return pArray;
}
```